# Matlab code performance improvement

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, matlab, multidimensional-array

I have a matrix A (MxN) and need to create a matrix B (MxNxN) by using A such that `B(:,1,1) = A(:,1)`, `B(:,2,2) = A(:,2)`,..., `B(:,N,N) = A(:,N)`. Currently I use,

```
B = zeros(size(A,1), size(A,2), size(A,2));
for i=1:size(B,3)
    B(:,i,i) = A(:,i);
end
```

Is it possible to use `repmat` or any other method to make this code run faster than it does now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using ["partial" linear indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/09/essence-of-indexing/) on the last two dimensions of `B`, as follows:

```
[M, N] = size(A);
B = zeros(M, N, N);
B(:, 1:N+1:N^2) = A;
```

Comment: Very interesting this new indexing thing, don't think I ever tried it! Very kool.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks! Yes, I haven't had many chances to use it either. I wasn't even sure how to call it, so I kind of made up the name "partial linear indexing". (Loren Shure doesn't give it a name, she just says "Indexing with fewer indices than dimensions")

Comment: Hmm, I think that is a fair name to it, something of an in-between thing!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`shiftdim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/shiftdim.html):

```
m = 3;
n = 4;
A = rand(m,n); % example data
C = bsxfun(@times,A,shiftdim(eye(n),-1));
```

`shiftdim` is used to map the N-by-N identity matrix to an 1-by-N-by-N array which is then multiplied by `A` and virtually replicated across the first dimension. This approach should be both memory-efficient and fast. Comparing to your `for` loop version:

```
B = zeros(size(A,1), size(A,2), size(A,2));
for i=1:size(B,3)
    B(:,i,i) = A(:,i);
end
```

Then `isequal(B,C)` returns `1`.

Comment: This works fine. I will let you know the performance improvement for a large matrix. Thanks horchler

Comment: And it is faster for a large input matrix. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you want to do, this should do the trick (you will need to replace the `4` and `5` in my example by `M` or `N`):

```
>> A = rand(4, 5) 

A =

    0.8147    0.6324    0.9575    0.9572    0.4218
    0.9058    0.0975    0.9649    0.4854    0.9157
    0.1270    0.2785    0.1576    0.8003    0.7922
    0.9134    0.5469    0.9706    0.1419    0.9595

>> B = permute(reshape(repmat(A, 1, 5), 4, 5, 5), [1 3 2]) ;
>> C = permute(reshape(repmat(eye(5, 5), 1, 4), 5, 5, 4), [3 1 2]) ;
>> T = C .* B
>> squeeze(T(1, :, :))

ans =

    0.8147         0         0         0         0
         0    0.6324         0         0         0
         0         0    0.9575         0         0
         0         0         0    0.9572         0
         0         0         0         0    0.4218
```

**Note:** I did not check the above code in MATLAB, I only checked it using `numpy` but this should do what you want. Here is an example in `python` using `numpy`:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> import numpy.matlib as matlib
>>> A = numpy.random.rand(4, 5)
>>> A
array([[ 0.44172719,  0.32698936,  0.53422512,  0.39081766,  0.09870158],
       [ 0.65483718,  0.50364349,  0.74913438,  0.87151756,  0.71811372],
       [ 0.54355853,  0.44174294,  0.61738783,  0.74293526,  0.1598779 ],
       [ 0.77675639,  0.204072  ,  0.69584264,  0.04263266,  0.24350847]])
>>> B = matlib.repmat(A, 1, 5).reshape((4, 5, 5))
>>> B
array([[[ 0.44172719,  0.32698936,  0.53422512,  0.39081766,  0.09870158],
        [ 0.44172719,  0.32698936,  0.53422512,  0.39081766,  0.09870158],
        [ 0.44172719,  0.32698936,  0.53422512,  0.39081766,  0.09870158],
        [ 0.44172719,  0.32698936,  0.53422512,  0.39081766,  0.09870158],
        [ 0.44172719,  0.32698936,  0.53422512,  0.39081766,  0.09870158]],

       [[ 0.65483718,  0.50364349,  0.74913438,  0.87151756,  0.71811372],
        [ 0.65483718,  0.50364349,  0.74913438,  0.87151756,  0.71811372],
        [ 0.65483718,  0.50364349,  0.74913438,  0.87151756,  0.71811372],
        [ 0.65483718,  0.50364349,  0.74913438,  0.87151756,  0.71811372],
        [ 0.65483718,  0.50364349,  0.74913438,  0.87151756,  0.71811372]],

       [[ 0.54355853,  0.44174294,  0.61738783,  0.74293526,  0.1598779 ],
        [ 0.54355853,  0.44174294,  0.61738783,  0.74293526,  0.1598779 ],
        [ 0.54355853,  0.44174294,  0.61738783,  0.74293526,  0.1598779 ],
        [ 0.54355853,  0.44174294,  0.61738783,  0.74293526,  0.1598779 ],
        [ 0.54355853,  0.44174294,  0.61738783,  0.74293526,  0.1598779 ]],

       [[ 0.77675639,  0.204072  ,  0.69584264,  0.04263266,  0.24350847],
        [ 0.77675639,  0.204072  ,  0.69584264,  0.04263266,  0.24350847],
        [ 0.77675639,  0.204072  ,  0.69584264,  0.04263266,  0.24350847],
        [ 0.77675639,  0.204072  ,  0.69584264,  0.04263266,  0.24350847],
        [ 0.77675639,  0.204072  ,  0.69584264,  0.04263266,  0.24350847]]])
>>> C = matlib.repmat(numpy.identity(5), 4, 1).reshape(4, 5, 5) * B
>>> C
array([[[ 0.44172719,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.32698936,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.53422512,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.39081766,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.09870158]],

       [[ 0.65483718,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.50364349,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.74913438,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.87151756,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.71811372]],

       [[ 0.54355853,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.44174294,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.61738783,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.74293526,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.1598779 ]],

       [[ 0.77675639,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.204072  ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.69584264,  0.        ,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.04263266,  0.        ],
        [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.24350847]]])
```

Comment: I think that this can produce the correct result, but the output of your Matlab code does not match the form of the OP's `B` array.

Comment: @horchler Yes, I am working on it... I wrote the code in Python and forgot that the OP wanted MATLAB. The problem is that python uses row storage while MATLAB uses column. ;)

Comment: @horchler Answer updated, don't really like it (much more uglier than my python script), and far more slower than you version...

Comment: @Holt. Thanks for your effort.